# Problems with # inside a verbatim that's inside a note

Tags: verbatim, pandoc

I'm trying to use a `#` character inside a verbatim that's inside a note :

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]

\note{\begin{verbatim}
 #
\end{verbatim}
}

\end{frame}
```

This produces the following errror :

```
>   ! Illegal parameter number in definition of \beamer@todo.
>    to be read again> 
>                    
>   l.5 }
```

How can I write the `#` character in a way that doesn't break the latex compilation ?

Thanks in advanced,

PS : This is related to the following problem in pandoc : 
https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/3293

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This will not work at all, since you cannot use the `verbatim` environment as argument of a macro, here `\note` (at least it looks as if `\note` takes an argument). When parsing this argument, `#` signals a parameter number that has to follow. To solve your problem you have to untangle `\note` and `verbatim` environment.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how to get the particular layout you may desire (no info was given), but the `verbatimbox` package can be used to get the `verbatim` content into the `\note`.

```
\AtBeginDocument{\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=left}}
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeamertemplate{note page}{\insertnote\par}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{verbbox}
 # verbatim
 \material $%here
\end{verbbox}
\note{\theverbbox}
Here is my slide
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]